How can an address that receives bytes through movs transfer bytes to another address that receives bytes through movups
Memory Viewer
I need to assign the value of the upper address to the lower one, but they have different commands, the first one has movups, and the second one has movss
I have this code in an auto-AOB script:
code: 
    movss [rbx+10],[rbx]
    jmp return

How do I fix this code so that everything works?
I tried to put just mov and movups instead of movss, but there is still an error

There are no x86 instructions with two explicit memory operands. You need to transfer the data into a register from the memory source and from that register to the memory destination.

I'm new to assembler, how do I transfer the date to the register? Via mov, movups or movss?

Replace the previous movss xmm0, [rsp+60] with movss xmm0, [rbx]?
